# Mac question about flowcharting

Tags: algorithms

Is there a flowcharting application like Raptor for Mac. I am using the OS X (Sierra) version. I use Raptor in Windows and need a similar application
for Mac.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question has nothing to do with computer _science_ so it's off-topic, here. You could try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

You could use MindNode or OmniGraffle (though OmniGraffle is more expensive), although these are more oriented towards mind-mapping than for flowcharting.

If you were looking for a free, web-based software, I've heard draw.io works pretty well. There really isn't much choice for macOS unfortunately, after all.

Comment: Welcome to the site! We recommend you take the [tour] and have a look at the [help centre](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to learn about what's on-topic here, since this question isn't.